# how to save both files minify and unminify JS in vite build?

Tags: vite

I want both files to be saved during the build , how do I do this in vite?
triggered only for one file:

```
minify: false
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help
https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#output-plugins

```
output: [
    {
        file: 'bundle.js'
    },
    {
        file: 'bundle.min.js',
        plugins: [terser()]
    }
]
```